# Can I co-host both Blazor Server and Blazor WASM Client as 2 deployment instances for the same app on production?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Blazor WASM has its advantages like speed on client side (after initial pre-load), offline support and can be served via CDNs.

But, Blazor WASM isn't suitable for SEO, pre-rendering doesn't really solve the issue because then the app essentially becomes Blazor Server which always has an open SignalR connection and needs a server round trip for each button click.

Can I host both versions of the app, and do some URL/DNS Routing magic so that the search crawlers use Blazor Server, but humans interact with Blazor WASM Client. I am looking for best of both worlds from a user experience standpoint.

Both Speed and SEO are critical in our project.

References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can do it. please refer to the following articles: [Hosting both Blazor Server and WebAssembly in single website](http://www.duracellko.net/posts/2020/06/hosting-both-blazor-server-and-webassembly) and [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0)